# Repeat group of rows in a table

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, paste

I currently have a file with 9 rows, and I am basically looking for a way to repeat that group of 9 rows over and over again combining it all into one file. My table looks something like this:

```
A   1   Cage    605
A   2   Cage    605
C   3   Cage    252
C   4   Cage    252
B   5   Vial    915
B   6   Vial    915
B   7   Vial    915
B   8   Vial    915
B   9   Vial    915
```

What I would look to do is have these rows repeated X number of times in a new file. For instance, if I wanted everything repeated twice (in reality I need to repeat this several thousand times) it would look something like:

```
A   1   Cage    605
A   2   Cage    605
C   3   Cage    252
C   4   Cage    252
B   5   Vial    915
B   6   Vial    915
B   7   Vial    915
B   8   Vial    915
B   9   Vial    915
A   1   Cage    605
A   2   Cage    605
C   3   Cage    252
C   4   Cage    252
B   5   Vial    915
B   6   Vial    915
B   7   Vial    915
B   8   Vial    915
B   9   Vial    915
```

I was able to find some similar question, but those people were just seeking to have the rows replicated. However, I need the rows replicated while maintaining the pattern shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash: `yes "$(< filename)"` will repeat the contents endlessly.

For a specific number:

```
function repeat_file {
    for n in $(seq $1); do
        cat "$2"
    done
}

repeat_file 2 filename
```